# Python selenium select modal

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the google map embed url using selenium. I am able to click the share button and the page shows a modal with share url and an embed url. However i am un able to switch the dialog box.
Here is my code

```
    browser.get('https://www.google.com/maps/place/%s?hl=en'%(code))
    time.sleep(3)
    share_class = "ripple-container"
    buttons = browser.find_elements_by_class_name(share_class)
    for but in buttons:
        x = but.text
        if x == 'SHARE':
            but.click()
    modal = browser.switch_to.active_element
    share = modal.find_element_by_id("modal-dialog")
    print(share.text)
```

here is the image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to switch to the modal dialog, you can access it just like you would any other HTML on the page. You can simplify your code to

```
browser.get('https://www.google.com/maps/place/%s?hl=en'%(code))
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button/div[.='SHARE']").click()
url = browser.find_element_by_id("last-focusable-in-modal").text
print(url)
```

But... if you read the dialog, you will see that it states

> You can also copy the link from your browser's address bar.

so the URL you are navigating to in the first line is what you are going to copy from the Share link so there's really no point. You already have the URL.